# Find the number of times a specific element occurs in an Array list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, collections

I am trying to find how many time one string occurs in an `ArrayList`. I managed to find by using `Collections.frequency(list,object);`

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Main> d = new ArrayList<Main>();

        Main m = new Main();
        m.setA("a");
        d.add(m);

        Main m11 = new Main();
        m11.setA("a");
        d.add(m11);

        Main m111 = new Main();
        m111.setA("a");
        d.add(m111);

        int c = Collections.frequency(d, m11);
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    private String a,b,c;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return a.equals(((Main)o).a);
    }     
}
```

In the above code I manage to find occurrences of `a`. But how can I find other stuff also, like if I want to find occurrences of `b` and `c`also? Is there a way I can do it? Can I have many equals function?

Comment: You can create a `HashMap<String, Integer>` and count the number of occurrences of each `String`.

Comment: hashmap not possible

Comment: user3029017 and Atri - combination of both logics will give you the exact result what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of `frequency`.

```
public static int frequency(Collection<?> c, Object o) {
    int result = 0;
    if (o == null) {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (e == null)
                result++;
    } else {
        for (Object e : c)
            if (o.equals(e))
                result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

So this works on equals method and you can't have more than one `equals`.

You have to manually iterate over the list and find the frequency for different properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Main> d = new ArrayList<Main>();

int counter = 0;
foreach( var item in d )
{
   if( item = "The string you desire" )
   {
       counter += 1;
   }
}

// This is the total count of the string you wanted in the collection
console.write(counter);
```

If you want to make this a generic function, it would just take 2 parameters, the collection, and the item you desire.